# Is there practical Attack on A5/1 Cryptosystem?

Tags: cryptanalysis

There are several and several attacks on A5/1 Cryptosystem, but most of them are impractical. In 2008, Elad Barkan , Eli Biham and Nathan Keller release a practical attack on GSM.

Is there any production of the attack? In another words, does exist any physical production that gets ciphertext as input and get Key or Plaintext in output(due to the EBN attack)?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you a little research? Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1) list the attacks on A5/1

Comment: @kelalaka I'd think this question asks more for an _implementation_ (that's what my reading of "a production" is) of the specific named attack than for a list of possibly efficient attacks.

Comment: @SEJPM the Wiki article also lists the rainbow tables  A5/1 Cracking Project, COPACOBANA. etc.

Comment: @kelalaka i know all of the attacks, but i search for a practical implementation step by step due to the attack,nor part of the rainbow attack.

Answer (score 1):

Elad Barkan has(Possibly had) a company called KeySee Software.
In Elads's words: "KeySee supplies software for off-the-air interception of GSM communications, as well as consulting services for computer security and encryption."

Knowing Elad, and the literature, I have every reason to believe they deliver what they promise.

As others mentioned in comments, Rainbow tables are available for download, the computational requirements don't seem all that difficult to do it yourself in 2019. Obviously there is a difference between having the Rainbow tables and a functioning attack.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of practical implementation will not be done typically by academic researchers and other open source researchers since the *theoretical* results, with enough practical details have already been published and are clearly indicating the weakness of A5.

If it's done by government agencies *for practical use* it won't be published/advertised.

And if some student or amateur group had implemented it, they'd be advertising it, by putting details online.

So, most likely, no.

Comment: USENIX is full with the converse of your claim. Also the rainbow table can be downloaded from [GDrive](https://opensource.srlabs.de/projects/a51-decrypt/wiki/wiki), `git clone git://git.srlabs.de/kraken`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is (are...)

https://youtu.be/wiFgDPaudtI

https://youtu.be/aS1PO0SGhh8

A5/1 cracking has been demonstrated by Karsten Nohl since 2009